# why using thread.sleep in java audio?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, audio

```
   {
           File sound=new File("audiocheck.net_whitenoisegaussian.wav");
           Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
           clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
           clip.start();
           Thread.sleep((clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000));//
        } catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException |  ex);
```

why using Thread.sleep in this code!!!? with sounds

Comment: How should we know?  Probably to pause the thread while the clip plays.

Comment: Because `clip.start()` plays the sound in a different thread.  The sleep call is waiting for it to finish by waiting for the Clip’s duration to elapse, although there are better ways to do so.